# Dynamically create cronjobs in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to dynamically create scheduled lambda calls in AWS? I have to create many scheduled lambda calls that. I am aware of CloudWatch rules, but they have a limit on the amount you can get. I also heard about [Cronally](https://cronally.com/), but they are not launched yet, and I'd rather do something like this on my own. I do not see an obvious solution without trade offs, but does the 'easy way' exist, or it all depends on the particular application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloudwatch events [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch) say the limit of 50 rules per account  can be raised on request so maybe they might be able to raise it high enough for your needs.

Alternatively you could just do one rule that fires a single "scheduler"lambda function every minute. that scheduler can contain a
Schedule of which functions get fired at which times and invoke the other lambda functions according to that schedule. You could even store the schedule in a dynamoDB  table or s3 bucket so don't need to update the lambda function itself to change the schedule.